# How to implement push notification in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am writing a **chrome** extension that will receive at some points messages. I would like to have that **little red circle** on the bottom-right side of my ico extension with 1,2,3... depending on the number of messages received by the user. More, if the user pushes on the extension and reads that/those message(s), that little circle will disappear

I've read some nice articles about how will I be able to implement such a thing but for now, all that I've come with is a basic notification which disappear after ten seconds.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Notification with Audio",
    "description": "notification",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1",
    "permissions": [
        "notifications"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

**background.js**

createNotification();
audioNotification();

```
function audioNotification(){
    var yourSound = new Audio('yourSound.mp3');
    yourSound.play();
}

function createNotification(){
    var opt = {type: "basic",title: "Your Title",message: "Your message",iconUrl: "your_icon.png"}
    chrome.notifications.create("notificationName",opt,function(){});

    //include this line if you want to clear the notification after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(function(){chrome.notifications.clear("notificationName",function(){});},5000);
}
```

Could somebody describe the process of achieving what I want ? It's a must to use the [GCM](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/cloudMessaging) service ?

Comment: Which part do you need help with? As stated (complete implementation of push) it's waaaaay too broad.

Comment: Basically, you have 2 unrelated questions here. How to make a badge with a number on your icon, and how to implement push "in general". What's worse, it's stated for both Chrome and Firefox. Please decide on which problem you want to tackle in this question - there's nothing wrong with asking several. I'm downvoting for now, but will be happy to undo it if you edit your question with the above in mind.

Comment: @Xan , I have changed a little bit the question so that the changes that I need will only be necessary for Chrome

Comment: Not enough. You have basically 2 questions here, unrelated - how to make a badge on the icon to attract attention, and a vague "how to implement push". Which is it?

Comment: How to make a badge on the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to present an icon that displays the number of unread messages and does something on click, then you want a [Browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction).

A browser action can *either* open a small page on click called a popup (useful if you want to display something) or trigger an `onClicked` event in the background page (useful if you want to do something else, like open a web page).

As for the counter, the standard way is to use the **badge**, which can be set with `setBadgeText` and `setBadgeBackgroundColor`. Alternatively, you can draw some sort of custom badge over your icon using a `<canvas>` and update the icon dynamically with `setIcon` - but that would go against UI traditions of Chrome.

[image: Badge sample]

---

As for push messages - GCM API is a ready solution, but you can implement your own; [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets) would be a suitable technology to do it.

If you have a more concrete question about that, ask it separately.